# Multi Model Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm building a sports league evite like web application. There are 3 models, all related to each other. Players (users), Teams, and Games. Teams have many players, and many games. Players have many games, and can have multiple teams. Games belong to teams and players.

```
Teams: have_many :players
Teams: have_many :games

Players: have_many :teams
Players: have_many :games

Games: belong_to :teams
Games: belong_to :players
```

Is there a way to create a "triple association" using a "has_many through" table? I'm leaning towards a "has_many through" and then tracking the status of each player's response in the "through" table. I'd also like to have both teams in the "through" table, that way I can do something like (player_id, team_id, game_id) and only create one game for both teams.

Or does what I have above work? Or am I completely off my rocker and going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :gameable, polymorphic: true
    end

    class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :games, as: :gameable
      has_many :players, through: :matches
    end

    class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :games, as: :gameable
      has_many :teams, through: :matches
    end

    class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :players
      belongs_to :teams
    end
```

Hope this will help you.